# Angular HttpTestingController testing response type blob error responses

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-httpclient

Trying to test the simple case of API call with some additional mapping done on both success and error responses.

```
    return this.http.post(someEndpoint, formData, {
      responseType: 'blob',
      observe: 'response',
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Accept': 'text/csv'
      })
    }).pipe(
      map(blobResponse => {
        // ...
      }),
      catchError( async (err: HttpErrorResponse)=> {
        const customErrorMessage = await err.error.text();
        throw customErrorMessage;
      })
    );
```

I'm able to test the success scenario logic using

```
    myApi.someMethod(mock).subscribe({
      next: (res) => {
        expect(res).toEqual(someResponse);
      }
    });


    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(someEndpoint);
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('POST');

    req.event(responseMock);

    httpTestingController.verify();
```

Unfortunately I can't test the error scenario the same way, as `req.flush(...)` with `HttpErrorResponse` as a param always results in the `Error: Automatic conversion to Blob is not supported for response type.` error.

I tried to use `req.error(...)` :

```
const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(someEndpoint);

...

req.error(new ProgressEvent('error'), {status: mockErrorStatus, statusText: mockErrorMessage});

...

httpTestingController.verify();
```

It seems to be working as code from catchError is reached but it fails as there is no blob in the mocked payload so `await err.error.text()` just fails.

Is there any known way to test such scenarios?
Maybe the code itself is written in a way that it is untestable?

I'm using jasmine 3.6, karma 6.3 and an Angular 16.